# Why when you sign in they can't know what is wrong?

Tags: forms, passwords

when someone sign in to website and write username and password wrong 
they said

> username or password wrong

why they can't know what is the wrong specifically username or password?

Comment: I don't see a programming question here, so I'm flagging to close. I'll answer here anyway: Security - You don't want to give a hacker any extra information to know what to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you don't want to give a hacker any information to work off of.  For example, if they're just putting in tons of usernames with random passwords and the site says that the password is wrong, the hacker knows they found an account and they can start working on the password.  The combination of not knowing if either is valid is definitely more secure.